# Clone a Git Repo on personal site

Tags: git, shell, git-bash

How can I clone a repo with SSH when the repo is on my personal site?

I connected through using

```
ssh user@site.com
```

Lets say the repo is in public_html/gitrepo/

would I do...

```
git clone https://user@website.com/public_html/gitrepo
```

?

Comment: Can you be more explicit on where is the repo? What are you using to expose your git repository through https?

In general you can't use ssh through https. ssh is a totally different protocol.

Comment: Take a look on this reading in order to clarify what you need. https://git-scm.com/book/ch4-1.html

Comment: You said you want to clone with ssh. So do not use https url, but ssh instead: `git clone user@website.com:public_html/gitrepo`. (assuming your repo is in `/home/user/public_html/gitrepo` on website.com server.